# Wildcard with SQL Replace function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a variable with value as below

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ROOT(10) AS TEN, ROOT(50) AS FIFTY, ROOT(70) AS SEVENTY'
```

I would like to get only `'TEN,FIFTY,SEVENTY'` from the variable

Below is what I tried:

```
REPLACE(@var, 'ROOT(%) AS', '')
```

Can anyone give me an idea on how to get to the desired output?

Comment: Does your sql support regexes?

Comment: I'd suggest using a split function for the comma, then getting the string after the `' AS '` with a simple substring with charindex. And avoid storing multiple values separated with comma, so you don't have these problems in the future.

Comment: You're asking how to *parse* a text line, not how to replace a few characters. SQL, the language, isn't good at string manipulation. Where did those values come from? If they came from an external file, the file should be parsed *before* inserting the data in the database. If the string is produced by concatenating values, the process could be modified to produce what you want, or even to *avoid* string concatenations

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @var varchar(max) = 'ROOT(10) AS TEN, ROOT(50) AS FIFTY, ROOT(70) AS SEVENTY'

select replace(replace(replace(@var,'ROOT(10) AS ',''),'ROOT(50) AS ',''),'ROOT(70) AS ','')
```

Comment: Thanks ! but in my case I need it to be dynamic, var value is not static it can vary based on input ...for var = 'ROOT(30) AS THIRTY' this wont work

Comment: and what if he will have thousands ROOT's?

Comment: @DBAHub. It's a problem. Replace doesn't support like or wildchars.

Comment: @SeaSharp the original problem is trying to do such stuff in SQL, no matter the RDBMS. Even if a product supports regular expressions, they aren't fast, can't take advantage of indexing. In this case, the OP is trying to *parse* a string, nor replace a few characters

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution using recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @var varchar(max) = 'ROOT(10) AS TEN, ROOT(50) AS FIFTY, ROOT(70) AS SEVENTY'

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT STUFF([var], patIdx, idx - patIdx, '') [var], 1 [rn]
    FROM (
        SELECT @var [var], PATINDEX('%ROOT([0-9]%) AS %', @var) patIdx, CHARINDEX(' AS ', @var) + 4 idx
    ) a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT STUFF([var], patIdx, idx - patIdx, ''), [rn] + 1
    FROM (
        SELECT [var], PATINDEX('%ROOT([0-9]%) AS %', [var]) patIdx, CHARINDEX(' AS ', [var]) + 4 idx, [rn] FROM CTE
    ) a
    WHERE PATINDEX('%ROOT([0-9]%) AS %', [var]) > 0
)

SELECT TOP 1 [var] FROM CTE
ORDER BY [rn] DESC
```